# Labeling indexes on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a multi-layer index in a dataframe. When I run

```
print(len(b.index.names))
```

I get 3. When I run

```
print(b.index.names)
```

I get [None, None, None].

How do I give each of the above index levels a unique name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
b.rename_axis(['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

Or

```
b.index.names = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign with list such that indexes are named `index_1`, `index_2`, and `index_3` respectively, if more they are named accordingly as well:

```
b.index.names = ["index_" + str(i+1) for i in range(len(b.index.names))]
```